# Java using too much CPU

Tags: java, eclipse, cpu-load, tomcat

Trying to use either Eclipse or Apache Tomcat pushes all 4 CPU cores to around 60% cpu usage, and trying to run both at the same time maxes them all out.

Tried deleting all the webapps I'd deployed to Tomcat, no effect.

Tried editing `eclipse.ini` to provide more memory (`-Xmx2048m`), no effect.

versions:

- java: 1.6.0_24
- eclipse: Indigo (3.7.2)
- tomcat: 5.5.35

Comment: Are you using openjdk or oracle?

Comment: openjdk, version 6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try installing [openjdk-7-jre [image: Install openjdk-7-jre]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openjdk-7-jre).